# Substring a JSON object value in an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I was wondering what would be the best way to accomplish getting a substring of a value from a JSON object that is being spit out in an `ng-repeat`. Currently I have:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat=" item in records | orderBy : '-score' | limitTo : 10 " ng-click="moreInfo(item)">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.score}}</td>
</tr>
```

And what is displayed on the page is `user-SmithJoe`. I was wondering if it is possible in the html to do something like `{{item.name.substring(5,item.name.length())}}`. I am sure that doesnt work, but hopefully you understand what I am trying to accomplish from that. I ultimately just want `SmithJoe` to be the output.

This is the js:

```
data2.forEach(function(r) {
  if (r && r.user && r.user.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchText.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
    $scope.records.push(r);
  }
});
```

It the for each part is just going through all of the returned json objects and adding them to `records[]` if they contain what I am looking for. So since I did it this way I didn't really see there any way to take a substring @ that point?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that doesn't work? I thought it would. What error message do you get when you do that?

Comment: IIRC, .slice(5) works

Comment: inside the html though?

Comment: Right before the `push` you could do `r.name = r.name.substring(5)` ... so you'd cut out the part that you don't want to show right in the model. Or you add another member to the object like `r.shortname = r.name.substring(5)` and use `{{item.shortname}}` in the binding

Comment: yes in html `{{item.name.slice(5)}}`, just try

Comment: @YOU. Thanks, simple & elegant. Idk why the `substring()` wasn't working but this works perfectly. Create an answer and I'll accept :)

Comment: substring also works, just .length is not method, so not .length(), but .length

Comment: oh, I guess that was my problem. I'm used to regular Java stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{item.name.slice(5)}}
```

should works :)

Answer (score 3):

Add a property to the object when you iterate:

```
data2.forEach(function(r) {
    if (r && r.user && r.user.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchText.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        r.prettyName = r.name.replace("user-", "");
        $scope.records.push(r);
    }
});
```

And output that name:

```
<td>{{item.prettyName}}</td>
```